# How could we add value + 5 to the entire column

Tags: excel

I have an excel file

sno, date time  , open , close

In the date and time colum I would like to change the time from EST or lets say add +5 hours to the entire column how could this be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates start from `B2` cell:

• Input `05:00:00` in column `E2`

• In `F2` input: `=B2+E2`

• Drag down `E2:F2` range down

Answer (score 1):

`1 Day` = `1`, so `5 hours` = `5/24`, or a fraction of 1.

In a new cell, add `=5/24`, then copy/paste values. You should have a hard-coded `0.208333333333333`

Now re-copy the hard-coded `0.208333333333333`.

Select the entire date column, and paste special using the *Add* functionality.

Then reapply date formatting as needed.

If it's easier for you to understand, you can use `=TIME(5,0,0)` instead of `=5/24`.

Comment: But I have a date along with the time in the same colum . Eg 09/12/2019 14:22:00 . OUTPUT : 09/12/2019 19:22:00

Comment: Date/times are just numbers. Just reapply the date formatting.

Comment: The answer is still not clear could you explain with an exmaple above why is it = 5/24 when I want to do value + 5

Comment: *Then copy/paste values... Now copy the cell* Which values and what cell?